# Error in python list indexing in forloop with inner while loop

Tags: python, algorithm, list, debugging, indexing

Here is my concurrent version of the code:

```
from collections import Counter
class Solution:
    def minWindow(self, s: str, t: str) -> str:

        left = 0
        right = float("inf")
        ref = Counter(t)
        necessary_count = sum(ref.values())
        curr_count = 0
        curr_dict = Counter()
        slow = 0
        for i in range(0,len(s)):
            c=s[i]
            if c in ref:
                curr_dict[c]+=1
                if curr_dict[c]<=ref[c]:
                    curr_count+=1
            while curr_count == necessary_count:
                if (i-slow)<(right-left):
                    left,right = slow,i
                s = s[slow]
                if s in ref:
                    curr_dict[s]-=1
                if curr_dict[s]<ref[s]:
                    curr_count-=1
                slow+=1
        if right == float("inf"): return ''
        return s[left:right+1]
```

example testcase:

```
Input: S = "ADOBECODEBANC", T = "ABC"
Expected Output: "BANC"
Actual Output:""
```

Currently, I am receiving and index error where i declare `c=s[i]`. When I went through the debugger, it throws the error right after I finish the programs first encounter of the while loop. Why does i violate the index of `s`  `(0<=i<len(s))` and the forloop stays within those constraints? Does it have to do something with my while loop?

Comment: what is the input you are trying?

Comment: And also how are you calling the function?

Comment: @SayandipDutta i updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does indeed have something to do with your `while` loop:

```py
s = s[slow]
```

The first time that this code is run, `slow` is 0, and `s` gets reassigned to its first character (and its length is now 1).

On the next iteration of your for loop, `c=s[i]` will raise an `IndexError` because `i` is 1, but `len(s)` is now 1.